# Vlookup query to find and highlight different data in a column

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup

I performed my vlookup and now I need to highlight the things that were different. There are over 5000 lines of data, so I don't really want to go through each line and to find different data, can anyone direct me in right direction ?

for example,

[image]

i would like to just highlight **KU, PBT, MU** and **STU** from the list.

Comment: I... am not sure how you picked KU, PBT, MU or STU from that list. What are you basing yourself on?

Comment: Conditional formatting .. [here](http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/questions/cond_format4_2010.php)

Comment: Use filters. Put the cursor in the table and go to Data->Filter

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at conditional formatting.  You can use it to colour cells that have particular values.